# Optimize Boolean Mask Assignment

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic

This question is similar in nature to: [Is -!(condition) a correct way to obtain a full-bitvector from a boolean (mask-boolean)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907111/is-condition-a-correct-way-to-obtain-a-full-bitvector-from-a-boolean-mask-b)

As part of a HW solution, I would like to implement a conditional check and subsequent assignment of all "1" or "0" bits to a 32bit int.

**My code is : `value & ~(!(x & y) - 1)`. If there is some overlap between x's and y's bits, value is set to 0, otherwise value is left alone.**

**My question is how to optimize this statement to reduce the number of operators involved.** Is this possible using only unary and binary integer operations `! ~ & ^ | + - * / % << >>` ?

Here is my code for some reference, it repeats the low-order n bits of x to word length:

```
int bitRepeat(int x, int n) {
/* Mask desired bits, shift and OR by larger intervals each time, return repeated pattern */    

/* Check for n = 32, set a to all 1's if n != 32 */ 
int nMax = ~(!(n & 31)-1);  

/* Mask low-order n bits */
int maskBits = ~(~0 << n) & x;  

/* Initialize shift factors */  
int n2 = n * 2; 
int n4 = n * 4; 
int n8 = n * 8; 
int n16 = n * 16;

/* Shift and OR masked bits by intervals n * x {x: 1,2,4,8,16}, check for overflow at each step */  
int overFlowMask = ~0 << 5;
maskBits = maskBits | maskBits << n;
maskBits = maskBits | ((maskBits << (n2)) & ~(!((n2) & overFlowMask) - 1));
maskBits = maskBits | ((maskBits << (n4)) & ~(!((n4) & overFlowMask) - 1));
maskBits = maskBits | ((maskBits << (n8)) & ~(!((n8) & overFlowMask) - 1));
maskBits = maskBits | ((maskBits << (n16)) & ~(!((n16) & overFlowMask) - 1));

return (maskBits & ~nMax) | (x & nMax);
}
```

Would implementing `unsigned` data in some capacity help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a lot easier (we want to fill an integer with n repeats of a bit pattern).

```
unsigned int bitRepeat(unsigned int x, int n)
{
   unsigned int answer = 0;

   while(x)
   {
     answer |= x;
     x <<= n;
   }

   return answer;
}
```

You need to use unsigned integers because shifting out the MSB of a signed integer can have unpredictable consequences. (Because the compiler might
optimise to x *= poweroftwo, and have arithmetical overflow traps set).

Since you can't use loops, it becomes a bit more difficult. As you
observed, if integers are 32 bits, then worst case is we double the
buffer five times.

so

```
int bitRepeat(int x, int n)
{
   unsigned int rack = x;

   rack = (rack << n) | rack;
   n *= 2;
   rack = (rack << n) | rack;
   n *= 2;
   rack = (rack << n) | rack;
   n *= 2; 
   rack = (rack << n) | rack;
   n *= 2;
   rack = (rack << n) | rack;

   return rack;
}
```

Unfortunately this is technically undefined behaviour if the shift goes
above the size of an integer. Your compiler might well accept it. But it's hard to suppress without a conditional.

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately I can't change `int bitRepeat(int x, int n)` or use loops/conditionals. Would storing `x` in an `unsigned` container help?